# I am trying to change image on hover and I cannot figure out what is wrong with code to get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-hover, image-preloader

I am having trouble getting the hover effects on the images. When hovered over I need them to switch images. I am not sure if the preload for the images is correct either. If you could let me know what is wrong in my code and how to fix it that would be great. Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My Favorite Video Games</title>
  <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  
   function preloadcachedImage() {
    var cachedImage = [
     "photo1.jpg",
     "photo1_alt.jpg",
     "photo2.jpg",
     "photo2_alt.jpg",
     "photo3.jpg",
     "photo3_alt.jpg"
    ];
       
    var images = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < cachedImage.length; i++) {
     images [i] = new Image();
     images[i].src = cachedImage[i];
    }
    
    $('#img1').hover(function() {
     $('#img1').attr('src' , 'photo1_alt.jpg');
    }, 
    function() {
     $('#img1').attr('src', 'photo1.jpg');
    });
    
    $('#img2').hover(function() {
     $('#img2').attr('src' , 'photo2_alt.jpg');
    }, 
    function() {
     $('#img2').attr('src', 'photo2.jpg');
    });
    
    $('#img3').hover(function() {
     $('#img3').attr('src' , 'photo3_alt.jpg');
    }, 
    function() {
     $('#img3').attr('src', 'photo3.jpg');
    });
   }
   
   preloadcachedImage();
  }); 
  </script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper" >
   <div class="cachedImage">
    <img id="img1" src="photo1.jpg" alt="">
    <br>
    <img id="img2" src="photo2.jpg" alt="">
    <br>
    <img id="img3" src="photo3.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <!--.images-->
  </div>
  <!--.wrapper-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your function name is `preloadcachedImage()` but you call `preloadMyImages()` on load.  Also dont declare functions inside the `$(document).ready();`

Comment: also, you have errors within your function to boot, it should read like this http://jsbin.com/duneduyipa/edit?js

Comment: I tried using everyones input so far. The images still won't change on hover, so not sure what else could be wrong

Comment: I fixed the issue. I just had to change the javascript source. Thanks everyone for your help